# Multiple select option selected will be view in another html element using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a multiple select option on html like this :

```
 <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectError1">Ditujukan untuk :</label>
     <div class="controls">
          <select id="email" multiple data-rel="chosen" class="input-xlarge" name="email[]">
              <?php
                  foreach ($atasan as $data) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $data['email'] . "'>" . $data['email'] . "</option>";
                  }
            ?>

           </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

My goal is, when user selected an or any option, the option that selected will be view in another html element like `<p id='emailSend'>This is the email : email1, email2... so on</p`.

I am newbie in jquery. I guess 'on change' or change can do this.

This is the jquery's code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emailSend').hide();

    $('email').change(function(){
        //any idea ???
    });

}
```

**EDIT**
I was wondering to increase my ability, how should I do if I want to append it on a input text like

```
<input type="text" id="emailSend" name="emailSend">
```

So, the jquery looked like this :

```
$("#email").change(function() {
        var elements = $("#email option:selected").length;

        $(".emailSend").html("");
        $.each($("#email option:selected"), function(index, element) {
            $(".emailSend").val($(this).html());
            if (index < elements - 1) {
                $(".emailSend").append(", ");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is :

```
$("#email").change(function() {
    var elements = $("#email option:selected").length;
    $("#emailSend").html("");
    $.each($("#email option:selected"), function(index, element){            
        $("#emailSend").append($(this).html());
        if (index < elements-1) {
           $("#emailSend").append(", ");
        }
    });
});
```

With `emailSend` being your block containing all the emails. Note that this solution allows you to handle multiple values.

EDIT : grammar :(

Comment: Removed my answer because this is the good one :) Although I might use `.val()` instead of `.html()`... but that's just me

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right, i didn't notice OP was using the same data for the option value and for option label :)

Comment: I have try it. Thanks, but the result is : email1email2email3. How to separate them like email1, email2, email3. Thanks again.

Comment: I did edit my previous post :) I just specified that a comma and a space must be added to the final content

Comment: As you may see in this little code, each time the value of your "select" is changed, the content of our email list is emptied and fulfilled with each value. That said, if the user does remove an option from his selection, it shouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: Thanks, if the one option is removed ,'<p>' is affected too. How bout remove the last comma ?

Comment: @FadlyDzil I did edit my comment to be able to retrieve the current index in the .each() iteration which allows us to detect if we're at the last step (where we shouldn't add a comma) or not

Comment: Thanks a ton, you give me a big lesson.